# get the string after certain character or specific character in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex

I have a pattern of strings like in column "remarks":

```
remarks
pay mode: called to pay
pay mode: cash
pay mode: bank deposit
pay mode: from third party
```

I have to select all the string after the `pay mode:`. One way is to retrieve all the strings after the first appearance of `:` in value or select all the strings from left after 9 characters from left.

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this and hope it helps you

```
Create table #table1
(
Remarks varchar(100)
)

Insert into #table1 values('pay mode: called to pay'),
('pay mode: cash'),
('pay mode: bank deposit'),
('pay mode: from third party')


Select substring(Remarks,11,len(Remarks)) from #table1
```

Better way is, you can also use CHARINDEX. Check this query:

```
Select SUBSTRING(Remarks, CHARINDEX(':',Remarks)+1, len(Remarks)) from #table1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `Substring` + `Charindex`

```
SELECT Substring('pay mode: called to pay', Charindex(':', 'pay mode: called to pay')
                                                + 1, Len('pay mode: called to pay'))
```

or Use `Right` + `Charindex`

```
SELECT RIGHT('pay mode: called to pay', Len('pay mode: called to pay') -
                                             Charindex(':', 'pay mode: called to pay'))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. In this case what if I've to check if there is any extra ":" present as the first character in the value and remove with ''. How can I do this?

Comment: @user4221591 - can you update the question with this scenario with relevant example and expected output

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `case` to be sure the string is in the format expected:

```
select (case when remarks like 'pay mode: %'
             then stuff(remarks, 1, 10, '')
             else remarks
        end)
```

Or, perhaps a more general solution:

```
select (case when remarks like '%: %'
             then stuff(remarks, 1, charindex(': ', remarks)+1, '')
             else remarks
        end)
```

EDIT:

As Firebird points out, the `case` is unnecessary when using `stuff()`.  That makes this solution more elegant for just the colon.  `charindex()` returns 0 when there is no match, so nothing happens in that case.  You can just do:

```
select stuff(remarks, 1, charindex(':', remarks), '')
```

However, to capture the space afterwards requires using `case()` or `ltrim()`.

Comment: AFAIK `Charindex` won't return `-1` when string is not found it will return `0`

Comment: @Fireblade . . . Very good insight.  However, there is still a problem because of the `+1` to get rid of the space afterwards.  So, you have a really elegant solution for `':'`, but it doesn't work quite as well for `': '`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(Remark,'pay mode:','')) Remark
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to split on the basis of string, use this as a SQL Server function. Define a sql server function as

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[split](
          @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),
          @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)
        ) RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))
        AS
        BEGIN
          DECLARE @xml XML
          SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'

          INSERT INTO @t(val)
          SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item
          FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)
          RETURN
END
```

You can call this function like `dbo.split('pay mode: called to pay', 'pay mode:')`